# Key I can hold down to only tab complete a folder

Tags: bash, autocomplete, cd-command

Say I have a directory like so:

```
 foo/
   bar.js
   bar/
```

if I `cd` into foo and then type "ba" and then hit tab, I won't get completion because a file name overlaps with a folder.

Is there a key I can hold with tab that will just give me the folder (or the file?)

Comment: Not in bash. `zsh` completion behaves closer to what you want.

Comment: @jordanm Bash has had selective completion for over a decade (a bit more than half as long as zsh has had it).

Comment: @jordanm riiiight then can you answer the original question?

Comment: still diggin' this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL,DR: add `. /etc/bash_completion` to your `.bashrc`.

To answer the exact question you asked, there is no such built-in commands. Bash has [commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Commands-For-Completion) to complete various kinds of objects (file names, user names, variable names, etc.) but not one that's restricted to directories.

However, unless you're running an antique version of bash, you can use **context-sensitive completion**, a feature added in version 2.04 which was released in 2000. Some distributions enable it by default; for others you need to install the [`bash-completion`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) package and activate it in your `~/.bashrc`. Most distributions provide a package called `bash-completion` and put the activation script in `/etc/bash_completion`, i.e. your `.bashrc` should contain the line

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```

After this, if you enter `cd`  and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, only directory names will be completed.

If you have a non-ancient version of bash (≥4.0), you can put `shopt -s autocd` in your `.bashrc`, and after this you can omit the `cd` command, so you can write just `bar` instead of `cd bar`. Tab completion will complete both command names from `$PATH` and directory names from the current directory (and `$CDPATH`) on the first word of the line.

Bash 4.0 also lets you write your own command line edition functions (earlier versions kinda did but you had to jump through hoops). So if you really want you could do that. [How to customize Bash command completion?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148497/how-to-customize-bash-command-completion/217916#217916) has a relatively complex example; search for `READLINE_LINE` and `complete` to find other examples.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are not getting any completions after typing `ba` is because you did not precede `ba` with the `cd` command. Bash realises that neither typing `bar.js<ENTER>` nor `bar<ENTER>` would make sense (one is a directory while another file `bar.js` is either not in `$PATH` and/or does not have the executable permission set), so it does not give you any completions at all.

However, if you precede the directory name with a `cd`, bash will see `bar` fits, and no other name does, and will perform a full completion:

```
$ ls
bar  bar.js
$ cd <TAB>
```

At which point the prompt will transform into

```
$ cd bar/ # This line
```