# how to pass argument as string outside which should execute particular function

Tags: bash

I have very long bash script, requirement is to execute script like command line.
If I execute

```
 ./script.sh arg1 arg2 create
```

As above if i pass string "create" along with "arg1" & "arg2" should execute particular function (like create_fn() ) of script.sh

Like above

```
./script.sh arg1 add
```

If i pass string "add" along with only arg1 --> should execute create_add() function.

Also , If if i press tab after "cr" should auto write "create" / ad  -> add

can anyone help me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, welcome to the site.

The answer to your question depends on how consistent the arguments are passed to the script.

**If** it is guaranteed that

- the argument "create" is only used when there are a total of three arguments, with "arg1" and "arg2" preceding "create", and similarly
- the argument "add" is only used when there are a total of two arguments, with "arg1" preceding "add"

then you can perform an `if` test inside your script operating on the builtin variable `$#` which contains the total number of arguments with which the script is called:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" == "3"  && "$3" == "create" ]]
then
   create_fn <possible arguments here>
elif [[ "$#" == "2" && "$2" == "add" ]]
then
   create_add <possible arguments here>
fi
```

To explain: In the `if` test we check if the number of arguments (`$#`) is 3 *and* the third argument (`$3`) is "create", and then call `create_fn` (possibly with arguments; you didn't specify if it takes any in your question); *or* if the number or arguments is 2 and the second argument is "add", in which case we call `create_add`.

If the order of command-line arguments, on the other hand, is arbitrary, you will have to implement a more intelligent parameter handling routine, and something like [getopts](/questions/tagged/getopts) would be your friend.

For more information about shell programming, have a look into the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Concerning **the second part** of your question: The feature you are looking for is called "bash completion" and is not a trivial thing, in particular since you want to auto-complete *command-line arguments* where the possible values can depend on the position of the currently typed argument in the list and the preceding items on the command-line. It is possible, but not trivial (see e.g. [How to customize Bash command completion?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148497/how-to-customize-bash-command-completion?rq=1)).

Comment: I will try and update you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the setup a bit and use option flags via `getops`. Those however need to be at the beginning and be single letters only. An example:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 add=no
 create=no
 while getopts "ca" option ; do
   case $option in
     a) add=yes ;;
     c) create=yes ;;
     \?) echo 'Invalid option. Aborted.' ; exit ;;
   esac
 done
#shift argument numbers so that file1 is $1 etc.
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [[ "$add" == "yes" ]] ; then
  do_add_procedure
elif [[ "$create" == "yes" ]] ; then
  do_create_procedure
else
  do_neither
fi
```

Depending on how you do the `if`-statement (i.e. split it into two statements), you now can even run both "create" and "add" by giving both options. However, `bash`-script arguments **must** be at the beginning of your command:

```
./script.sh -a file1 file2
```

Comment: I tried append your script, but this even work for -> ./script.sh arg1 create  or   ./script.sh create   .   my need is - should only work when passing arg1 arg2 create else throw error  . where arg1 and arg2 is constant when passing create.

Comment: @Tom15 Total number of arguments is given as `${#}`, so check if this is `2` after `shift`ing. (else abort). If you want specifically two fixed files, check if `${1}` and `${2}` are the correct strings.